# Can we pumpup the 100cc bikes power?

Tags: engine

I m very new to engineering field so may be its bit funny for uh guys but My question is , is that possible to increase 100cc bike engine into 150 cc ... or can we built more power in 100 cc bikes. if yes then how ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The easy answer is "yes". If you give us more information about the bike in question, we could probably help you better understand what you might be able to do with it.

Comment: You can spend a lot of time and money for relatively small power gains. You have to remember though, you're starting with a 100cc engine, and it will only go so far. Depending on your goals and restrictions, it might be cheaper and easier to get a bigger bike. Remember, there is no replacement for displacement.

Answer (score 3):

You can virtually always gain power from any engine, it just depends on how much work and money you've willing to put into it. Sure you can gain a little power from a 100cc bike.

As far as tuning goes.. after removing any regulation restrictors, changing air filters, exhausts and fueling are normally the first route to take as these are the quickest and cheapest options. But to go the whole hog, you'd be looking at an engine job, were the cylinder bore would be opened out. 150cc would likely be too much to get from a 100cc barrel, however a suitable barrel from a 150cc bike could be adapted and machined. Stresses and loads on other components should always be taken into account when increasing power.

Further tuning.. Can include things like cyl block and head skimming, cam/port/valve oversizing, profiling, porting & gas flowing, balancing etc, as well as buying lighter components, or lightening them by removing excess material.

Basically your looking to get the air/fuel mixture into and out of the engine as quickly and as smoothly as possible, whilst getting the most power from it.

Following any modifications an engine must be tested and evaluated.

Comment: Comprehensive answer with lots of « meat » for the OP to research and improve their knowledge...